# is there a closed expression for this function ??

Tags: sequences-and-series

given the function $$ f(z)= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n^{2}}z^{n} $$

I know that this series satisfies the functional equation

$$ f(z)=1+\frac{z}{2}f(z/4) $$

since the coefficients satify the recurrence relations

$$ 2a_{n+1} =a_{n}2^{-n} $$

with $ a_{0}=1 $

but what is the closed expression for this series ??

Comment: Can we even solve when $z=1$?  And if so, are we going to have to use theta functions?

Comment: Does your series converge? Edit: I did not see the minus :D. Sure it converges.

Comment: @MrYouMath I think it does.

Comment: @Jose Garcia The correct functional equation is $f(z)=1+(z/2)f(z/4)$. As for the closed expression, it is my habit that before I start agonizing "does it have a closed expression? or does it not?", I simply ask Mathematica. If the sum has a known closed expression, then Mathematica (almost surely) knows it. I fed your sum to Mathematica, which after a moment or two regurgitated it unchanged. So, it seems that even if the sum has a closed expression, it was not yet found by any mathematician, be it alive or already dead.

Comment: It's a Jacobi theta function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function